# Finding the Difference between 2 Dates in MSSQL from multiple different Rows

Tags: sql-server, datediff, message

When using MSSQL, is there any way using SQL statements to DATEDIFF the dates from 2 different rows. We are trying to gauge response times.

We have a messaging system that stores the UniqueKey, Note, DateNoteSent, and User that sent the note.

Data Sample:

```
UniqueKey      Note                 User     DateOfNote                 
L4H2390039D2   This is a test.      23       2018-01-30 16:15:14.2965479
L4H2390039D2   Test received.       15       2018-01-30 18:10:00.3482044
DH38D2DJ8382   Call me ASAP.        17       2018-01-30 16:22:34.1971033
DH38D2DJ8382   Will do.             35       2018-01-30 16:25:34.1749088
DH38D2DJ8382   Sorry I missed you.  17       2018-01-30 16:28:34.1991463
```

Is it possible to find the difference between the date/times in messages with the same UniqueKey?

Some of the messages have more than 2 messages in the chain and would.

I would the like to have a final column that shows the time duration from the previous message named ResponseTime that shows either a time ie: 12:34:33 or 1 hr 37mins.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: use `lead` function to compare to the next row

Comment: How would you Calculate the date difference for messages that have unique keys which occur more than twice ?

Comment: What are you expecting for output from your sample data? That looks like a datetime2 datatype? Keep in mind that datediff returns the number of intervals crossed and does not provide you with something hours:minutes:seconds.

Comment: I would prefer the output to be in a time format.  I apologize for my lack of SQL skills.  I figured I could break it down with multiple DATEDIFF statements for hours, mins, and secs.

Comment: other option for multiple grouping is to get `min` and `max` and get the difference

Comment: Can you post a new column that would be your expected values? It isn't clear what you want for the three rows of "DH38D2DJ8382"

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry I wasnt more clear when asking the question. I would like the duration in time between messages (response time) in either 12:32:45 format or 1hr 23min 45sec.

Comment: I get that part. But is it always the duration between the current row and the "previous" one? Even if there are more than 2 as in the case I mentioned? And which part(s) of this do you need help with? There is the logic to look at the previous row and there is the work to get the difference between two datetime values in the format you want.

Comment: @SeanLange Just the duration from the row above (previous note) but only for each distinct UniqueKey #.  So if there were 3 records, the first message in the chain wouldnt have a duration, but the next note would have the duration in time from the note above...and so on until the next unique key, which will start the process over.  I dont even know if this is possible in SQL.

Comment: Pretty easy actually. Sounds like you need to look at LEAD - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql and Lag - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql

Comment: @SeanLange I started messing around with the LEAD function and was able to use the DATEDIFF with to get the difference from the next row, but ran into the problem with the last record with the UniqueKey, as it would show the next UniqueKeys duration.  This might be able to be determined by the MAX and MIN fuction as maSTAShuFu stated above; I cant wrap my head around this.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: In your LEAD function you need to add a PARTITION BY clause.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  The PARTITION BY clause was the piece that I needed, along with the LEAD and LAG.

Comment: Awesome. Glad you were able to get it sorted out. And thanks for attempting this and not just asking others to do it for you. I wish others shared that willingness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `LAG` function. Result is in format `hhh:mm:ss`

```
select
    UniqueKey, Note, [User], DateOfNote
    , concat(right(concat('000',diff/3600), 3), ':', right(concat('00',diff%3600/60), 2), ':', right(concat('00',diff%60), 2))
from (
    select 
        *, diff = datediff(ss, lag(DateOfNote) over (partition by UniqueKey order by DateOfNote), DateOfNote)
    from 
        #Table1
) t
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This worked perfect. Thanks to everyone, for the help.

Comment: Good solution, but requires SQL 2012 and up. Microsoft Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL prior to 2012 then alternative to LEAD function:

```
create Table #Table1 (
    UniqueKey varchar(20),
    Note varchar(100),
    [User] varchar(10),
    DateOfNote datetime
    );

-- add some records 
Insert into #Table1 (UniqueKey,Note,[User],DateOfNote) values  ('L4H2390039D2','This is a test.','23',CAST(N'2018-01-30 16:15:14.296' AS DateTime))
Insert into #Table1 (UniqueKey,Note,[User],DateOfNote) values  ('L4H2390039D2','Test received.','15',CAST(N'2018-01-30 18:10:00.348' AS DateTime))
Insert into #Table1 (UniqueKey,Note,[User],DateOfNote) values  ('DH38D2DJ8382','Call me ASAP','17',CAST(N'2018-01-30 16:22:34.197' AS DateTime))
Insert into #Table1 (UniqueKey,Note,[User],DateOfNote) values  ('DH38D2DJ8382','Will do.','35',CAST(N'2018-01-30 16:25:34.174' AS DateTime))
Insert into #Table1 (UniqueKey,Note,[User],DateOfNote) values  ('DH38D2DJ8382','Sorry I missed you.','17',CAST(N'2018-01-30 16:28:34.199' AS DateTime))
Insert into #Table1 (UniqueKey,Note,[User],DateOfNote) values  ('DH38D2DJ8382','Sorry I missed you.','17',CAST(N'2018-02-02 08:01:34.199' AS DateTime))


select t.Number,t.UniqueKey,t.DateofNote,tnext.DateofNote,datediff(minute, t.DateofNote, tnext.DateofNote) as DiffMinutes,CONVERT(varchar(12), 
       DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, t.DateofNote, tnext.DateofNote), 0), 114) as hourMinute,
        cast(datediff(minute, t.DateofNote, tnext.DateofNote) / 1440 as varchar) + ' days ' + cast((datediff(minute, t.DateofNote, tnext.DateofNote) % 1440) / 60  as varchar) + ' hours ' + cast(datediff(minute, t.DateofNote, tnext.DateofNote) % 60 as varchar) + ' minutes' as DaysHoursMinutes

from (
select * 
,ROW_NUMBER() over ( ORDER BY UniqueKey,DateOfNote) AS Number
from #Table1 

)t join
     (select * 
,ROW_NUMBER() over ( ORDER BY UniqueKey,DateOfNote) AS Number
from #Table1 

) tnext
     on t.Number = tnext.Number - 1 and t.UniqueKey = tnext.UniqueKey
order by t.UniqueKey,t.DateofNote
```

Comment: This is close....but it doesn't work if the time difference is more than 24 hours.